# select two pandas column with np.select

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to solve a pandas data frame problem,

I have a data frame, which contains three columns:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'operation': ['data_a', 'data_b', 'avg', 'concat', 'sum', 'data_a', 'concat'], 
             'data_a': list(np.random.uniform(-1,1,[7,2])), 'data_b': list(np.random.uniform(-1,1,[7,2]))})
```

[image]

Column 'operation' represent merge column, so if there is 'data_a' value in Column 'operation', it means take that particular row's data_a value, if there is 'avg' operation, then take the average of 'data_a' and 'data_b' of that particular row so on.

What I am expecting in the output, a new column contains the values as per the operation column's merge functions

[image]

What I have tried:

```
dataframe['new_column'] = 'dummy_values'

for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    
    if dataframe['operation'].iloc[i]  == 'data_a':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = dataframe['data_a'].iloc[i]
    elif dataframe['operation'].iloc[i] == 'data_b':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = dataframe['data_b'].iloc[i]
    elif dataframe['operation'].iloc[i] == 'avg':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = dataframe[['data_a','data_b']].iloc[i].mean()
    elif dataframe['operation'].iloc[i] == 'sum':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = dataframe[['data_a','data_b']].iloc[i].sum()
    elif dataframe['operation'].iloc[i] == 'concat':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = np.concatenate([dataframe['data_a'].iloc[i], dataframe['data_b'].iloc[i]], axis=0)
```

Above solution is quite slow, so I tried np.select method as below

```
import numpy as np
con1 = dataframe['operation']  == 'data_a'
con2 = dataframe['operation']  == 'data_b'


val1 = dataframe['data_a']
val2 = dataframe['data_b']

dataframe['new_column'] = np.select([con1,con2], [val1,val2])
```

But If I am selecting two columns with np.select, It's giving error :

```
import numpy as np
con1 = dataframe['operation']  == 'data_a'
con2 = dataframe['operation']  == 'data_b'
con3 = dataframe['operation']  == 'avg'



val1 = dataframe['data_a']
val2 = dataframe['data_b']
val3 = dataframe[['data_b', 'data_a']].mean()


dataframe['new_column'] = np.select([con1,con2,con3], [val1,val2,val3])
```

Error message

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

How to select different conditions with np.select?

Comment: dataframe[['data_b', 'data_a']].mean(axis=1) ?

Comment: @BEN_YO add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What is `take_a`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Corrected.

Comment: What is `concat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `axis = 1` , make sure all the condition and value are in the same shape

```
import numpy as np
con1 = dataframe['operation']  == 'data_a'
con2 = dataframe['operation']  == 'data_b'
con3 = dataframe['operation']  == 'avg'



val1 = dataframe['data_a']
val2 = dataframe['data_b']
val3 = dataframe[['data_b', 'data_a']].mean(axis = 1)


dataframe['new_column'] = np.select([con1,con2,con3], [val1,val2,val3])
```

Comment: Thanks, Bdw Is there any better solution than this in terms of performance and time complexity?

Comment: I am dealing with quite large nth dim arrays and looking for fast solution.

Comment: Thanks, It's a huge jump in execution time. :)

Comment: I just checked the values of the function, axis =1 is giving NaN, Please check the output

Comment: @AadityaUra if the row contain all NaN , the mean will be NaN

Comment: No, the row contains values, Please run above example only, you'll get the NaN result.

Comment: @AadityaUra that is list type column what mean of dataa and datab will output

Comment: What's the solution? Should I convert it into array before taking mean? But I can only store list in pandas if it's nth dim

Comment: @AadityaUra I mean , [2,4] and [4,8] so the mean will be [3,6] ?

Comment: I want the mean along the axis 0, so in your example, Yes it will be [3,6]

Comment: @AadityaUra change to val3 = [[(s + t) / 2 for s , t in zip(x,y )]for x, y in zip(dataframe['data_a'],dataframe['data_b'])], there is no way to speed it up, since most of pandas function dose not work for cell type list

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

Comment: I also tried `np.mean(list(zip(dataframe['data_a'],dataframe['data_b'])),0)` but no luck.

Comment: @AadityaUra I try you sample , my solution work, please check the different between you real data with sample

Comment: check this. `https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NLDDN491hy9yqDy7DuRB8hMYYlmUK8FE?usp=sharing`

Comment: Can you check please?

Comment: @AadityaUra sorry I can not download and check the link~

Comment: please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63756980/np-select-with-more-than-two-pandas-column