# np.select with more than two pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I am trying to solve a pandas problem statement. The panda's data frame looks like this :

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
import time
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'operation': ['data_a', 'data_b', 'avg', 'concat', 'sum', 'data_a', 'concat']*100, 
             'data_a': list(np.random.uniform(-1,1,[700,2])), 'data_b': list(np.random.uniform(-1,1,[700,2]))})
```

[image]

Column `'operation'` represent merge column, so if there is `'data_a'` value in Column `'operation'`, it means take that particular row's data_a value, if there is `'avg'` operation, then take the average of `'data_a'` and `'data_b'` of that particular row so on.

What I am expecting in the output, a new column contains the values as per the operation column's merge functions

[image]

I am dealing with many rows with nth dim of NumPy array.

I have tried two solutions but both are quite slow.

The first solution, with normal python loop :

```
# first solution

start = time.time()
dataframe['new_column'] = 'dummy_values'

for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    
    if dataframe['operation'].iloc[i]  == 'data_a':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = dataframe['data_a'].iloc[i]
    elif dataframe['operation'].iloc[i] == 'data_b':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = dataframe['data_b'].iloc[i]
    elif dataframe['operation'].iloc[i] == 'avg':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = dataframe[['data_a','data_b']].iloc[i].mean()
    elif dataframe['operation'].iloc[i] == 'sum':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = dataframe[['data_a','data_b']].iloc[i].sum()
    elif dataframe['operation'].iloc[i] == 'concat':
        dataframe['new_column'].iloc[i] = np.concatenate([dataframe['data_a'].iloc[i], dataframe['data_b'].iloc[i]], axis=0)
        
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

# 0.3356964588165283
```

Which is quite slow, the Second solution is pandas apply method :

```
# second solution
start = time.time()
def f(x):
    if x['operation']  == 'data_a':
        return x['data_a']
    elif x['operation']  == 'data_b':
        return x['data_b']
    elif x['operation']  == 'avg':
        return x[['data_a','data_b']].mean()
    elif x['operation']  == 'sum':
        return x[['data_a','data_b']].sum()
    elif x['operation']  == 'concat':
        return  np.concatenate([x['data_a'], x['data_b']], axis=0)
        
dataframe['new_column'] = dataframe.apply(f, axis=1)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)

# 0.2401289939880371
```

Which is also quite slow. I am trying to work on NumPy select method to solve this problem:

```
# third solution

import numpy as np
con1 = dataframe['operation']  == 'data_a'
con2 = dataframe['operation']  == 'data_b'
con3 = dataframe['operation']  == 'avg'
con4 = dataframe['operation']  == 'sum'
con5 = dataframe['operation']  == 'mul'



val1 = dataframe['data_a']
val2 = dataframe['data_b']
val3 = dataframe[['data_b', 'data_a']].mean()
val4 = dataframe[['data_b', 'data_a']].sum()
val5 = dataframe[['data_b']]* dataframe[['data_a']]


dataframe['new_column'] = np.select([con1,con2,con3,con4,con5], [val1,val2,val3,val4,val5])
```

which is giving error :

```
~/tfproject/tfenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_shape(*args)
    189     # use the old-iterator because np.nditer does not handle size 0 arrays
    190     # consistently
--> 191     b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    192     # unfortunately, it cannot handle 32 or more arguments directly
    193     for pos in range(32, len(args), 31):

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

How can I solve this error and is there any other optimized method to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: How big is your actual dataframe, and does this represent all the functions you wish to apply?

Comment: I've never seen storing the operation as a string in a column.   You can definitely vectorize parts of this, but I think this workflow will have scalability/organization issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize this with pandas masking, so that you are only doing the operations needed, but still have the advantages of vectorization.  For brevity df is your dataframe:

```
df['new_column'] = np.nan
mask = df['operation']=='data_a'
df.loc[mask, 'new_column'] = df.loc[mask, 'data_a']
mask = df['operation']=='data_b'
df.loc[mask, 'new_column'] = df.loc[mask, 'data_b']
mask = df['operation']=='avg'
df.loc[mask, 'new_column'] = (df.loc[mask, 'data_a'] + df.loc[mask, 'data_b'])/2
# etc
```

Comment: Awesome, 3.447386 straight jump in speed.